# How to obtain method object for generic interface implementation in Java

Tags: java, generics, annotations, guava

In my case I want to find out if [`apply`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html#apply%28F%29) method's parameter for given implementation of [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) interface is annotated [`@Nullable`](http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/Nullable.html?is-external=true). Method to be implemented:

```
boolean isNullableArgument(Class<? extends Function<?,?>> function);
```

I don't know how to get implemented `apply` method from `function` class.

---

E.g. there could be `Function` implementations like this:

```
new Function<String,Integer>() {
    public Integer apply(String input) { … }
    public Integer apply(Integer input) { … }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the possible function implementation you describe would actually be legal. Have you tried it?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I've found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.TypeUtils;

public class FunkUtils { private FunkUtils() {}

    public static boolean isNullableArgument(Class<? extends Function> functionClass) throws Exception {
        Map<TypeVariable<?>,Type> typeArgs = TypeUtils.getTypeArguments(functionClass, Function.class);
        TypeVariable<?> argTypeParam = Function.class.getTypeParameters()[0];
        Type argType = typeArgs.get(argTypeParam);
        Class argClass = TypeUtils.getRawType(argType, null);
        Method applyMethod = functionClass.getDeclaredMethod("apply", argClass);
        Annotation[] argAnnos = applyMethod.getParameterAnnotations()[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < argAnnos.length; i++) {
            if (argAnnos[i] instanceof Nullable) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

There is a bug  in TypeUtils.getTypeArguments in commons-lang3 version 3.1, but it is fixed in 3.2, that is under development now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty solution. Don't copy and paste it directly - it's only meant as an example to get you started.

```
static boolean applyHasAnnotation(
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") final Class<? extends Function> functionType,
        final Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType
) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
    //for each directly implemented interface,
    for (final Type interfaceType : functionType.getGenericInterfaces()) {
        //if the interface is parameterized,
        if (interfaceType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            final ParameterizedType genericInterfaceType = (ParameterizedType)interfaceType;
            //if the interface is Function
            if (genericInterfaceType.getRawType() == Function.class) {
                //get the type argument for T
                final Type inputType = genericInterfaceType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                //get its raw type
                final Class<?> rawInputType =
                        (inputType instanceof ParameterizedType)
                        ? (Class<?>)((ParameterizedType)inputType).getRawType()
                        : (Class<?>)inputType;
                //use it to find the apply implementation
                final Method applyMethod = functionType.getDeclaredMethod("apply", rawInputType);
                //for each annotation on its first (and only) parameter,
                for (final Annotation inputAnnotation : applyMethod.getParameterAnnotations()[0]) {
                    //if its type is the specified annotation type, return true
                    if (inputAnnotation.annotationType() == annotationType) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //a more complicated inheritance hierarchy has defeated us
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Function info not found.");
}
```

In actuality, you'll want to code the various concerns separately:

- finding the generic interface on the implementing type
- looking up the `F` type argument to the generic interface
- looking up the `apply` implementation
- checking its parameter for a given annotation

As pointed out in the code, this solution easily breaks for more complicated type hierarchies, for example:

```
abstract class LongFunction<T> implements Function<Long, T> { }
```

A `new LongFunction<String> { }` would be a `Function<Long, String>` but the above method would not location the generic `Function` interface on its runtime type.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you question right, you want to do some validation of the annotation in the apply method. You would need to use reflection [this case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) (specially [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterAnnotations%28%29)). It would be something like (I will just make a draft omitting the exceptions):

```
this.getClass().getMethod("apply", parameter.getClass()).getParameterAnnotations()
```

Comment: I don't think the OP knows what `parameter.getClass()` is at runtime. Look at the method that they want to implement: `boolean isNullableArgument(Class<? extends Function<?,?>> function);`.

Comment: The main problem is how to get `parameter` from your “draft”.